# How to reason about this 'adder with memory' circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, digital-logic, memory, counter, adder

I'm reading through "Code" by Charles Petzold and I had a question about the following circuit illustrated in the book: [image: adder with memory]

Let's assume that the latches in the 16-bit counter and the 8-bit latch are edge-triggered D latches. Thus, when `clk` goes from 0 to 1 the counter will naturally 'increment' (e.g. `0007`hex to `0008`hex) and the 8-bit latch will 'save' its contents.

However, it seems that the 16-bit counter would 'increment' when `clk` goes from 1 to 0 too because in the implementation of a counter the book offers the following circuit: [image]

Note how the first bit of the counter is just inverted `clk`. Thus, the 'adder with memory' circuit proposed wouldn't work, right? Because we'd only be adding every other number in memory?

Comment: Are you sure that /Clk is the first bit of the counter? Not Q1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from chapter 14, where it introduces the 8 bit ripple counter:

[image: Excerpt 1 from chapter 14 'Code' by Charles Petzold]

You'll notice that it refers to this circuit as a **frequency divider**. It then goes on to point out, via the timing diagram, that this makes up a sort of binary counter:

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
```

So, as a counter, it works!

But we can't use this counter with other logic blocks, because they can only sample the counter on the rising clock edge, as that's the point of a synchronising clock. However, if you only look at Q1-Q3 it works as a counter that is able to be sampled on the rising clock edge. I've made this timing diagram showing a "real" counter at the top and the `not-clock` line and how it varies all over the place.

[image: Timing diagram]

The following bits of texts that follow this circuit then talk of it being ripple counter:

[image: Excerpt 2 from chapter 14 'Code' by Charles Petzold]

[image: Excerpt 3 from chapter 14 'Code' by Charles Petzold]

You'll see that the author then goes on to point out that *synchronous counters* are *more sophisticated* and all of the outputs change on the rising clock edge.

I would say that in Chapter 17: Automation, when the author starts talking about a 16-bit counter (now with a new CLR signal) that he's transparently started to use the term "counter" to mean "synchronous" counter that counts for each rising clock edge, rather than the original frequency divider/ripple counter.

Answer (score 2):

No, these are **rising-edge** triggered flip-flops. Nothing happens to the outputs when the clock falls from 1 to 0.

The text is a bit confusing because most authors use the word "latch" to refer to a level-sensitive bistable element and use the word "flip-flop" to refer to an edge-triggered bistable element. The little triangle shape at the Clk input signifies that these are indeed edge-triggered flip-flops.

Comment: I understand that these are rising edge triggered flip flops but the leftmost (least significant) output bit of the counter is just inverted clock. This leftmost output bit specifically doesn't just change on the rising edge - it seems to change whenever clock changes.

Comment: What makes you think that the inverted clock is being used as a data bit? I don't see any reason for that assumption. There are many different kinds of counters.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson See my answer as it contains excepts. The author specifically shows the `¬clk` line as being the LSB of a binary counter. However I don't think the author intended THIS counter being the one used in his fledgling computer a few chapters later.